# Disable Wordpress Yoast SEO on Single Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to disable the Wordpress Yoast SEO on a single page because it's conflicting with a different plugin.

I tried following this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391891/remove-yoast-wordpress-seo-on-a-page), adding this code to **functions.php**:

```
add_action('template_redirect','remove_wpseo');

function remove_wpseo(){
    if ( is_page(944)) {
      global $wpseo_front;
      remove_action( 'wp_head', array($wpseo_front, 'head'), 2 ); // <-- check priority
    }
}
```

The above did not work, so I then ran across [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-yoast-on-certain-pages-no-longer-working-after-update), and tried to change it to below, which of course resulted in a 500 error.

```
add_action('template_redirect','remove_wpseo');

function remove_wpseo(){
   if ( is_page(5526)) {
     global WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()
     remove_action( 'wp_head', array(WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance(), 'head'), 2 ); // <-- check priority
   }
}
```

Any ideas on how I might go about disabling Yoast SEO on a single page?  Should I do this from **functions.php** or somewhere else?  I think I'm close, but not quite there.

Comment: "Of course" resulted in a 500 error? What was the error? I'm guessing `global WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: I don't know the specific error, but Chrome said something about the server being unreachable.  But yeah, likely syntax issues.

Comment: If you get a 500 error, you need to consult your server's logs for the details.

Comment: This is true.  Unfortunately, I only have access to Wordpress and FTP.  It's not my server.  (Belongs to a friend of a friend's).  However, the 500 error is not the current issue, as it's no longer throwing a 500 error since I removed the erroneous code.  I'm simply attempting to determine a better way to disable Yoast SEO following the two links I provided as a guide.

Comment: Well, `global WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()` isn't valid PHP. Try removing the line entirely, it's unnecessary.

Comment: I know and I did.  I'm basically back to my first snippet.  Which returns true, but it is not working.  That's why I was trying to follow https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-yoast-on-certain-pages-no-longer-working-after-update which I think will help, but I'm not sure how to take the information in that post and apply it to my current situation.

Comment: @Dodinas If you have access to the FTP, then you should set WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG to true in wp-config.php and then access the log to determine the exact issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Here is the corrected code which is working:

```
add_action('template_redirect','remove_wpseo');

function remove_wpseo(){
    if (is_page(5526)) {
        global $wpseo_front;
            if(defined($wpseo_front)){
                remove_action('wp_head',array($wpseo_front,'head'),1);
            }
            else {
              $wp_thing = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();
              remove_action('wp_head',array($wp_thing,'head'),1);
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me. Is there anyway you could revisit this?

Comment: @smack-a-bro check out my answer. Hope it helps you! :)

Answer (score 2):

As of Yoast version 14.0, They have changed the way of disabling Yoast SEO output. This is the new method.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_wpseo' );

function remove_wpseo() {
    if ( is_page ( 5526 ) ) {

       $front_end = YoastSEO()->classes->get( Yoast\WP\SEO\Integrations\Front_End_Integration::class );

       remove_action( 'wpseo_head', [ $front_end, 'present_head' ], -9999 );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beware, as the document title html tag is also removed, if filtered by Yoast.

Comment: There is an updated answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391891/remove-yoast-wordpress-seo-on-a-page/63098462#63098462

Comment: This solution helped me resolve the WPSEO_Frontend critical error. Thank you!