# How to remove Yoast from blog posts page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, yoast

I am running into an error were Yoast keeps pulling blog posts that are for members only and causing login screen to pop up. When I disable Yoast across the whole website it works. But i need to be able to keep keep the plugin without running into errors like this.

Comment: When you mean pulling posts, where is this pulling happening? What should be happening and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kyon147 I have a page that is a blog section, blog pulls in all the posts. Some post's are set to members only so it takes away its members only content. So Yoast still picks up that section for members only and pulls up login 3 times. I know its coming from Yoast because it pulls in meta data and when I deactivate Yoast it works. I tried to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845968/disable-wordpress-yoast-seo-on-single-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in to your WordPress website. When you're logged in, you will be in your 'Dashboard'. On the left-hand side, you will see a menu. In that menu, click on 'SEO'.

[image]

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any option for custom apply plugin in yoast. If you find any error then change plugin and use All in One SEO Plugin. This is best.

Answer (score -1):

Yoast SEO is a WordPress plug-in designed to help you improve some of the most important on-page SEO factors–even if you aren’t experienced with Web development and SEO. This plug-in takes care of everything from setting up your meta titles and descriptions to creating a sitemap. Yoast even helps you tackle the more complex tasks like editing your robots.txt and .htaccess.
Some of the settings may seem a little complex if you’re new to SEO and WordPress, but Yoast created a complete tutorial to help you get everything set up. And the team at WPBeginner made this handy video to help you get set up quickly.